# How do you create a project in a specific group via GitLab API?

Tags: rest, curl, gitlab

I tried to use GitLab API to create a new project. This worked, but this is in my user space:

```sh
        curl \
            --header "Authorization: Bearer ${GITLAB_API_TOKEN}" \
            --request POST \
            "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/?name=$test-proj"
```

But I wanted to do it under a specific group with group_id <group_id> (I blanked it here). The most sensible approach that occured to me was:

```sh
        curl \
            --header "Authorization: Bearer ${GITLAB_API_TOKEN}" \
            --request POST \
            "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/<group_id>/projects/?name=test-proj
```

But this did not work. Are there any suggestions on how I could achieve this?

I consulted the following references

- https://forum.gitlab.com/t/create-a-new-project-in-a-group-using-api/1552
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-project

The GitLab documentation mentions the `path` or `namespace_id` attribute (although I would actually be in search of a `group_id` attribute). I am not sure about `path` and how to specify that. I tried - without success - to retrieve the `namespace_id` via

```sh
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_API_TOKEN}" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/namespaces"
```

It is well possible that I might not have the rights to do the required operation. Therefore a reference to an official (GitLab) documentation together with a test curl command that works would be very helpful to me - thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both users and groups are considered "namespaces" as far as the Gitlab API is concerned, so you can use either a group ID or a username in the `namespace_id` field. You can see this in use by getting a single namespace with either a Group ID (that you can see in the `/groups` API call, or from a Group's "profile" page) or a username:

```
# this will show the namespace details of the Group with ID 54
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${TOKEN}" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/namespaces/54

# this will show the namespace details of the User with username my-username
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${TOKEN}" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/namespace/my-username
```

Comment: Can someone please paste the actual `curl` command to create repo under the namespace.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone looking for the direct command:

**STEP 1:**

Navigate as below and identify the group ID from GUI:

Admin Area -> Groups -> GroupName

[image]

**STEP 2:**

Construct the command with two parameters viz., **name**, **namespace_id**

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <myprivatetoken>" -X POST "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?name=myexpectedrepo&namespace_id=38"
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that with the [`glab` CLI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/glab/), this should be easier.

See [`glab repo create`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/blob/main/docs/source/repo/create.md):

```bash
# create a repository under a group using the current directory name
$ glab repo create --group glab-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the appropriate access level, you can assign a git remote to your local repository that includes your group name. Then, the push event will trigger GitLab to create the remote repository.

```
$ mkdir project_name && cd $_
$ echo "# project_name" > README.md
$ git init; git add .; git commit -m initial
$ GITLAB_HOST="gitlab.com"
$ git remote add origin git@${GITLAB_HOST}:group_name/project_name.git
$ git push origin HEAD
```

Then, point your browser to `${GITLAB_HOST}/group_name/project_name`

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/#specify-who-can-add-projects-to-a-group

Comment: This works, however, the project was created as private.  Is there a way to use this method and have the project created as public?

Comment: Possibly. I know that you can use the GitLab API to make a request to toggle the repo from private to public.

Comment: Link to the documentation for this: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/#create-a-new-project-with-git-push