# How to create different projects within a group in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I would like to create a list of projects within a "group" using the terminal in my machine. The group is private and I'm assuming I need a personal access token to reach it.

I saw in Gitlab API I should use POST command for this: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-project. But I don't see how to specify the group I want to create it into. Using this question: [How do you create a project in a specific group via GitLab API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65081356/how-do-you-create-a-project-in-a-specific-group-via-gitlab-api), I could write the command:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: my-personal-access token" -X POST "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?name=mylaboratory%2Fgroupname%2Fproject name"
```

After that I'm getting:

`{"message":{"name":["can contain only letters, digits, emojis, '_', '.', dash, space. It must start with letter, digit, emoji or '_'."],"path":["can contain only letters, digits, '_', '-' and '.'. Cannot start with '-', end in '.git' or end in '.atom'"]}}`

Here is my example url:

https://gitlab.eth.ch/api/v4/projects?path=lasec%2Fstudent-repos-cs372-2021%2Fgroup31

Is there a way to specify these new projects should disable rewriting commit history?

**Try 1**

Fixed changing .com to the relevant extension.

**Try 2**

From another computer the error `curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)` goes away, this may be related to the connection as pointed in the comments.

**Try 3**

Comment: Since you're specifying an access token but still getting `401 Unauthorized`, it means the user whose token you're using doesn't have access to the Group you're trying to add the project to. A 401 can either mean you're not authenticating at all (but you are passing the Token, so this isn't the problem) or that you don't have access to the resource you're operating on.

Comment: @AdamMarshall you're right, in fact i use a domain different for .com and that's why I was getting 401 Unauthorized. I updated my question, because even after fixing that, I get another error.

Comment: Try adding `--http1.1` to your curl command.

Comment: @AdamMarshall indeed there seemed to be something wrong with the connection. From home it works. However, it keeps complaining on the syntax, which to me looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute you're looking for in the API is the `namespace_id`, and should be the ID of the group that you'd like to create the project within. If you wanted to create a nested group structure, each group you create can accept a `parent_id` which should be the ID of its parent.